# Differentiating between SVG mask and original SVG shape when animating

Tags: css, svg

I'd like to be able to apply an SVG mask to a shape I am animating but keep the mask element from being transformed through the animation. In other words, the mask stays static while the shape being masked is transformed.

In the example here, how would I keep the radius of the masking circle at 8?

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  0%{
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 30%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
 70%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
 100%{
  transform: scale(2.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.ripple {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation: ripple 3s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="circle-mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="8" cx="50" cy="50" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle id="main-circle" class = "ripple" r="15" cx="50" cy="50" mask="url(#circle-mask)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<circle>` in a group (`<g>`) element. Then apply the mask to the group instead.

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  0%{
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 30%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
 70%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
 100%{
  transform: scale(2.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.ripple {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation: ripple 3s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="circle-mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="8" cx="50" cy="50" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g mask="url(#circle-mask)">
    <circle id="main-circle" class = "ripple" r="15" cx="50" cy="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```